# How to call a system parameter from custom Python code in Odoo?

Tags: python, odoo

I'm running `Odoo 12` and I'd like to set up an automated action after a new Opportunity is created.
This automated action would be some custom Python code which calls a system parameter, gets its value and stores it in a field in the new opportunity's record.
Afterwards, that system parameter should be increased by 1 so another new opportunity doesn't have the same number.

How do you get/set a system parameter from python code?

I've created a system parameter with key `"customParameter"`and value 10122.
The field where this parameter should be put is called `"x_studio_deal_quotation_id"`, within a new opportunity.

I've got a little experience in Python, so I've no idea how to call upon this parameter. Can someone help me out? Or is there an easier way to achieve the same?
A big thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello and welcome on Stack Overflow. Could you give an [example of your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), with the expected result and the current result ?

Comment: @BertrandGazanion I simply tried`record[("x_studio_deal_quotation_id")] = customParameter
customParameter += 1` and the output error I get when I create a new opportunity is: _ValueError: <class 'NameError'>: "name 'customParameter' is not defined" while evaluating_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find what I'm looking for on my own, this is the code I used:

```
record[("x_studio_deal_quotation_id")] = record.env['ir.config_parameter'].get_param('customParameter')
var = record.env['ir.config_parameter'].get_param('customParameter')
var = int(var)
var += 1
record.env['ir.config_parameter'].set_param('customParameter', var)
```

In this function I called my system parameter by using `record.env['ir.config_parameter'].get_param('customParameter')`
I had to convert it to `int` because I got some error that the type wasn't right.
Finally, I add 1 to my variable value and write the same system parameter with the new value by using:`record.env['ir.config_parameter'].set_param('customParameter', var)`

Comment: Why not using Odoo's sequences (ir.sequence) for this? It's more powerful than using a simple system parameter.